# Obtaining current GCC exception model

Tags: gcc, mingw-w64

`g++` is built using either the `DWARF2`, `sjlj` or `seh` exception model.  [MinGW-builds](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/) provide various builds of `g++` that have different exception models.  I would like to be able to determine from the `gcc` toolchain what exception model is being used.  Is there a `g++` argument that will dump the default exception model of the compiler?

Comment: Looks like you can determine if gcc is using `sjlj` by checking the output of the assembly compilation looking for `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume` or `_Unwind_Resume` as that's what the [configuration script](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob_plain;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/configure;hb=HEAD) for `libstdc++` does

Comment: You can also check for `--enable-sjlj-exceptions` in the output of `gcc -v`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Edit:** Originally, I was testing for the configuration flags that are described in `g++ -v`.  As Jonathon Wakely points out in the comments, this is *not a good thing to do*.

An inspection way to do it is to compile to assembly:

```
struct S { ~S(); };
void bar();
void foo() {
  S s;
  bar();
}
```

The result of `g++ -S <filename> -o output.s` have the following exception references in them:

**`MinGW-4.8.1-x86-posix-sjlj`:**

```
.def    ___gxx_personality_sj0; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
.def    __Unwind_SjLj_Register; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
.def    __Unwind_SjLj_Unregister;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
.def    __Unwind_SjLj_Resume;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

**`MinGW-4.8.1-x86-posix-dwarf`:**

```
.def    ___gxx_personality_v0;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
.def    __Unwind_Resume;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

**`MinGW-4.8.1-x64-win32-sjlj`:**

```
.def    __gxx_personality_sj0;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
.def    _Unwind_SjLj_Register;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
.def    _Unwind_SjLj_Unregister;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
.def    _Unwind_SjLj_Resume;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

**`MinGW-4.8.1-x64-posix-seh`:**

```
.def    __gxx_personality_seh0; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
.def    _Unwind_Resume; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

**`MinGW-4.8.1-x64-posix-sjlj`:**

```
.def    __gxx_personality_sj0;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
.def    _Unwind_SjLj_Register;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
.def    _Unwind_SjLj_Unregister;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
.def    _Unwind_SjLj_Resume;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

**`FC17-g++-4.7.2-x64`:**

```
.cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
.globl  __gxx_personality_v0
call    _Unwind_Resume
```

Looks like we should search for `__gxx_personality_([a-z])(0-9]+)` and then compare the first capture group to:

- `v` = `dwarf`
- `seh` = `seh`
- `sj` = `sjlj`

Comment: This is incorrect, as the [docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) say, the default (i.e. what's used when you don't use any `--enable` or `--disable` options) depends on the platform.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan.  Still looking at working out the exception model via compiling code.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, I updated the answer, taking out the configuration flag checking, thanks for helping out with that.  I added some examples of the compilation of the exception handling snippet that I found in the `stdlibc++` configuration script and then looked at the assembly to determine the correct base personalities.  I used the following as reference: http://www.hexblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Recon-2012-Skochinsky-Compiler-Internals.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Just to complement the answers above, GCC has a predefined macro allowing to recognize at compile time whether SJLJ exception model is used:

> `__USING_SJLJ_EXCEPTIONS__`
>
> This macro is defined, with value 1, if the compiler uses the old mechanism based on setjmp and longjmp for exception handling.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html

According to documentation, it is available since at least version 3.1.1; I have just tested it on GCC 7.1 (under MinGW-w64).

Answer (score 0):

For me, finding corresponding DLL for each exception model works:
`libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll (DWARF)`
`libgcc_s_seh-1.dll (SEH)`
`libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll (SJLJ)`
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19791995/16550663

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).