# How do I compile and link a 32-bit Windows executable using mingw-w64

Tags: linux, mingw, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit, mingw-w64

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and installed mingw-w64 using `apt-get install mingw-w64`. I can compile and link a working 64-bit version of my program with the following command:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ code.cpp -o app.exe
```

Which generates a 64-bit *app.exe* file.

What binary or command line flags do I use to generate a 32-bit version of app.exe?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

That depends on which variant of toolchain you're currently using. Both *DWARF* and *SEH* variants (which come starting from GCC 4.8.0) are only single-target. You can see it yourself by inspecting the directory structure of their distributions, i.e. they contain only the libraries with either 64- or 32-bit addressing, but not both. On the other hand, plain old *SJLJ* distributions are indeed dual-target, and in order to build 32-bit target, just supply `-m32` flag. If that doesn't work, then just build with `i686-w64-mingw32-g++`.

### BONUS

---

By the way, the three corresponding *dynamic-link libraries* (DLLs) implementing each *GCC exception model* are

1. `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` (DWARF);
2. `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll` (SEH);
3. `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll` (SJLJ).

Hence, to find out what exception model does your current MinGW-w64 distribution exactly provide, you can either

1. inspect directory and file structure of MinGW-w64 installation in hope to locate one of those DLLs (typically in `bin`); or
2. build some real or test C++ code involving exception handling to force linkage with one of those DLLs and then see on which one of those DLLs does the built target depend (for example, can be seen with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on Windows); or
3. take brute force approach and compile some test code to assembly (instead of machine code) and look for presence of references like `___gxx_personality_v*` (DWARF), `___gxx_personality_seh*` (SEH), `___gxx_personality_sj*` (SJLJ); see [Obtaining current GCC exception model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17968530/1743860).

Comment: Is there an easy way to determine whether a Mingw installation is DWARF/SEH/SJLJ? What does `apt-get install mingw-w64` typically result in?

Comment: @bluenote10, I've expanded the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very helpful information! If SO would allow it, I would now upvote _twice_.