# What does an executable file compilation depends on?

Tags: gcc, compilation, operating-system, 32bit-64bit, cpu-architecture

Let assume that I want to compile a C program for a platform. I know that I must specify CPU architecture in compilation because of differences of instruction sets between different CPU architectures. I also know that I must specify the destination platform operation system because of the differences between executable file structures and system calls and ... between different operation systems.

**Q1:** The question is that if I need to specify the 32bit or 64bit of OS (not of the CPU architecture) too?

In the other word let assume that I have two systems:

1. 64bit CPU + 32 Bit Microsoft Windows
2. 64bit CPU + 64 Bit Microsoft Windows

Is there any difference in compilation a program for above systems?

**Q2:** When I add `-m32` in the options of `gcc` compiler, what is this `32` for? Is it for Operation System or it is for CPU architecture?

Comment: It also depends on the shared libraries you link to and on the structure of system types as defined by the header files on compile time. Also the compiler optimizations define a minimum feature set provided by the CPU. The -m is only a subset of the target architecture as described here: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2009-10/msg00280.html - I would say don't use it.

Comment: Why you say me don't use it? Even if I have a 32bit CPU arch?

Comment: Yes don't use it directly, use -march=i386 instead. And consider not to do crosscompiling it is harder to get the environment correct.

Comment: @eckes Thank you. How can I specify type of OS (64bit vs 32bit os)? Should I specify it?

Comment: You already accepted the answer so I assume it helped.

Comment: @eckes Yes it helped, but I still don't know how I can specify type of OS (64bit vs 32bit os) in the compilation time.

Comment: You are confused. You have one single common OS kernel which is providing several runtime environments and ABIs.

Comment: I am not an expert in GCC for Windows but normally you have to use a GCC produced for the intended target. You would select the target by using the right compiler. According to this there is at least one multi target version for mingw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690504/how-do-i-compile-and-link-a-32-bit-windows-executable-using-mingw-w64 you did not say what compiler you use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The question is that if I need to specify the 32bit or 64bit of OS (not of the CPU architecture) too?

You don't specify an [Operating System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) (you have only one OS running on a given machine; to run several of them use an [hypervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor) or some [VM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine)). You specify & choose an [Application Binary Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (ABI) since *some* OSes are able to offer several ABIs (and [runtime systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_system)).

> Is there any difference in compilation a program for above systems?

Yes, there is some difference (think of `sizeof(void*)` at least; also the 64 bits ISA uses more registers and the ABI could define different calling conventions, by passing more arguments thru registers). I can't tell more about Windows, which I don't know.

> When I add -m32 in the options of gcc compiler, what is this 32 for?

Dive into the documentation of GCC, notably the [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) chapter.

It is some [x86 option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html):

> The -m32 option sets int, long, and pointer types to 32 bits, and generates code that runs on any i386 system.
>
> The -m64 option sets int to 32 bits and long and pointer types to 64 bits, and generates code for the x86-64 architecture. For Darwin only the -m64 option also turns off the -fno-pic and -mdynamic-no-pic options.

Read also about the [x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) (which is a Linux specific thing).

I can't say more about Windows specific (which I don't know and never used). But I will explain what is happening on Linux. I leave you to seek similar knowledge for your proprietary Microsoft operating system.

On Linux, the operating system [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) can be configured (at kernel build time) to accept both 32 bits and 64 bits [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executables and provide a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) runtime environment for both architectures. Such kernels are able to execute with [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) both 32 bits executables, and 64 bits executables and provide two different [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)s (one for `-m32` for 686 [instruction set architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture), another for `-m64` for x86-64 ISA) for them. Notice that the *same* OS kernel enable executions of binary [executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) in either 32 bits or 64 bits mode.

I don't know Windows, but I could imagine that Microsoft provide also two different runtime environments & ABIs, one for 32 bits [686](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P6_(microarchitecture)) ISA and another for 64 bits [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) ISA. Maybe one of them is optional and needs to be installed or bought separately (I really don't know and I don't care).

It is up to you to dive into Microsoft documentations to find the details of the differences.

See also [x86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) wikipage.

I recommend reading something like [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/) (freely downloadable, chapter by chapter) to understand more the role of an OS, and also more about the [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) ISA, including its [long mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_mode).

Of course you need to care of other dependencies (or [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming))). Read about [DLL hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell) & [dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell).

Comment: So the `sizeof(void*)` depends on the OS and not depends on the CPU arch? Or it depends on both?

Comment: It depends on the CPU mode which is limited by the arch of the CPU and selected by the OS (win64 on x64 can run 32 and 64Bit executables)

Comment: If it depends of CPU mode only, then there must be no difference between compilation for both system 1 and system 2. Because both have the same CPU. Am I misunderstand something?

Comment: Yes, you are misunderstanding