# How to compile in MinGW on X86 and X64?

Tags: c, mingw

The following situation. As I understand it, 64-bit MinGW will only compile on X64. Then there is a 32-bit compiler on both systems. Can you please tell me how to compile separately for each platform X86 and X64, what compilers, and how to compile one application right away for 2 platforms?

Comment: this question should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690504/how-do-i-compile-and-link-a-32-bit-windows-executable-using-mingw-w64

Comment: *MinGW* (32/64) contains a bunch of executables (e.g. *gcc* compiler). 32bit executables run on 32 and 64 bit platforms, while 64bit executables only run on 64bit platforms. the *gcc* compiler is able to produce both 32 and 64 bit executables, regardless of its architecture. By default it produce executables for the same architecture as itself. You can force the target architecture by specifying `-m32` or `-m64`. arguments. What *OS* are you on?